# General Method to solve Simultaneous Partial Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$${\partial z \over \partial x}f(x,y,z)+{\partial z \over \partial y}g(x,y,z)=h(x,y,z)   $$
$${\partial z \over \partial x}F(x,y,z)+{\partial z \over \partial y}G(x,y,z)=H(x,y,z)   $$

$$f(x,y,z)={x-x_1 \over {\sqrt {(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+(z-z_2)^2} }}-{x-x_2 \over {\sqrt {(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+(z-z_2)^2} }} $$

$$g(x,y,z)={y-y_1 \over {\sqrt {(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+(z-z_2)^2} }}-{y-y_2 \over {\sqrt {(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+(z-z_2)^2} }} $$

$$h(x,y,z)={z-z_1 \over {\sqrt {(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+(z-z_2)^2} }}-{z-z_2 \over {\sqrt {(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2+(z-z_2)^2} }}    $$

$$F(x,y,z)=(y-y_1)(z-z_2)-(y-y_2)(z-z_1)  $$
$$G(x,y,z)=(x-x_2)(z-z_1)-(x-x_1)(z-z_2) $$
$$ H(x,y,z)=(x-x_1)(y-y_2)-(x-x_2)(y-y_1) $$

$ x_1, y_1, z_1, x_2, y_2, z_2 $ Are constants

What is the standard approach to solving these equations? I've gone through my textbook, but the author has not discussed this case. Moreover, I'm not being able to word my problem correctly, as a consequence, the Google Searches on the Internet are resulting in utter failure. Please help

Thank You.

Comment: Looks like you solve the linear system (algebraically) for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$. Then you have an equation of the form $\nabla z = P(x,y,z)$, where $P(x,y,z)$ is a vector of two components. Then *if* there is a solution, then it arises as the solution to the families of ODEs $z_x = P(x,y,z(x))$ (for each fixed $y$) and $z_y=P(x,y,z(x))$ (for each fixed $x$). Of course these could be\ completely arbitrary ODEs with the way you have written the problem, so there is no way to just write down the solution.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: A simple situation of this type would be $f \equiv 1,g \equiv 0,F \equiv 0,G \equiv 1$. Then you need to solve the ODEs $z_x = h$ (for each fixed $y$) and $z_y = H$ (for each fixed $x$). But again, $h$ and $H$ could depend on $z$ in an extremely complicated way, so these are not trivial ODEs, even when you completely decouple the two equations.

Comment: It would improve the Question if you spell out what are the knowns and what are the unknowns (for which you seek a solution).

Comment: I've made new edits to the question...